# Limit involving multiple factorials

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, binomial-coefficients

> Let $n, k\in\mathbb N_0$ be fixed (where $k\leq n$), and $S_N\in\mathbb N$ be a sequence such that $\lim_{N\to\infty} S_N/N=p$ for some fixed $p\in(0,1)$.
> Show that $$\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{S_N! (N-S_N)!(N-n)!}{(S_N-k)!(N-S_N-n+k)!N!}=p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.$$

Is there any easy way to evaluate this limit? Rewriting the left hand side to binomial coefficients does not seem to help, $$\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{{S_N\choose k}{N-S_N\choose n-k}}{{N\choose n}{n\choose k}},$$ at least I don't see a way to start from there.

Comment: Did you try to use Stirling's formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will use Stirling's Approximation in the form:

$$n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi }n^{n+\frac12} e^{-n} $$

Consider, for fixed $r$,

$$\lim_{m \to \infty} m^{-r}\binom{m}{r} = \lim_{m \to \infty} m^{-r} \frac{m!}{r!(m-r)!} $$

$$ \sim \frac{1}{r!}\lim_{m \to \infty} m^{-r} \frac{\sqrt{2 \pi }m^{m+\frac12} e^{-m}}{\sqrt{2 \pi }(m-r)^{m-r+\frac12} e^{-(m-r)}} $$

$$ = \frac{e^{-r}}{r!}\lim_{m \to \infty}  \left( \frac{m }{m-r}\right)^m \left( \frac{m }{m-r}\right)^{-r+\frac12}  $$

$$ = \frac{e^{-r}}{r!}\lim_{m \to \infty}  \frac{1}{\left( 1-\frac{r}{m}\right)^m} \left( 1-\frac{r}{m}\right)^{r-\frac12}  $$

$$ = \frac{e^{-r}}{r!} e^r \, 1 = \frac{1}{r!} $$

So now we can use your rewriting in terms of binomial coefficients:

$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{S_N! (N-S_N)!(N-n)!}{(S_N-k)!(N-S_N-n+k)!N!} = \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{{S_N\choose k}{N-S_N\choose n-k}}{{N\choose n}{n\choose k}}$$

$$ = \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{\frac{{S_N}^k}{k!}\frac{(N-S_N)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}}{\frac{N^n}{n!}{n\choose k}}$$

$$ = \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{{S_N}^k\,(N-S_N)^{n-k}}{N^n}$$

$$ = \lim_{N\to\infty} \left(\frac{S_N}{N}\right)^k\,\left(\frac{N-S_N}{N}\right)^{n-k}$$

$$=p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$